# is there a way we can conditional loading of snippets to only product page in shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need to add the snippet only in product page how can I stop it loading on other pages?
`{% render "custom" %}` added to `theme.liquid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a conditional tag based on the template object, like `{% if template contains "product" %}{% render "custom" %}{% endif %}`